# AppStore Connect displayed screenshots wrong colorspace

Tags: ios, app-store, screenshot, app-store-connect

Does anybody know a way to force **AppStore Connect** to use the right **colorspace** when displaying screenshots?
This problem has never occurred in the past, but know I'm facing this new issue.

Here is the original screenshot, before it's uploaded:
[Screenshot with right colorspace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZDyTM.png)

And here is the AppStore Connect screenshot: [Screenshot with wrong colorscheme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GSNin.png)

I have tried applying a different color profile to the image and then re-uploading it to AppStore Connect, but nothing changed for me.

Furthermore, I've noticed that at first it seems that AppStore Connect is using the right colorspace, but after saving and reloading the page, the wrong colorspace is used again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a **solution** for this so I've decided to share it here, just in case someone else needs it.

Prior to upload to **AppStore Connect**, you need to:

1. Remove the `alpha channel` from the PNG image, using `Preview` on **macOS**.
2. Open the screenshot image using the `ColorSync Utility` of
   **macOS**.
3. Select `Match to Profile`.
4. Choose the right `ColorSync Profile`.
5. Click `Apply` to save the changes to the screenshot image.
6. Select `Assign Profile` and repeat step **4** and **5**.
7. Select `Apply Profile` and repeat step **4** and **5**.
8. Finally, press **`CMD + S`** to save the changes.

Then upload your screenshot image to **AppStore Connect** and everything should be fine.

Here is the [ColorSync Utility User Guide](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/colorsync-utility/csyncad0012c/4.14.0/mac/10.14).

Comment: Unfortunately, as of September 2019 this does not work. Image looks like it's using the correct color profile when you upload it, but after reloading the page it's back to sRGB

Answer (score 0):

One solution that I found worked for me was converting the screenshots to sRGB using Sketch. Going to Edit > Change Color Profile > sRGB IEC61966-2.1 then exporting the images as JPG gave them the correct colour in the App Store. Photoshop works also.

Note that once you upload them to Connect it will still say and look like P3, but once they get uploaded, they will be fine.

Comment: But the issue is with colors that exist in P3 but not in sRGB, and getting them to display in the App Store on P3 devices. So not sure how this addresses that.